# Access "User Information" with Azureauth package in R Shiny webapp

Tags: r, shiny, azure-active-directory, information-retrieval, azure-authentication

Hi I am using AzureAuth to authenticate for R Shiny WebApp. I need current user email ID who is  using the shiny webapp. Below is the code structure. The email ids for every time the app is open by the user must be stored. Current roadblock is only to get the user details. Since I am new to this could'nt find any examples which shows how to fetch the details using AzureAuth package features

```
  load.lib <- c("AzureAuth","shiny","shinyjs","httr")
  install.lib <- load.lib[!load.lib %in% installed.packages()]
  for(lib in install.lib) install.packages(lib,dependencies=TRUE)
  sapply(load.lib,library,character=TRUE)
  ######### Setting the local port ###############
  redirect <- "http://localhost:8100"
  
  port <- httr::parse_url(redirect)$port
  options(shiny.port=if(is.null(port)) 80 else as.numeric(port))
  ######### Authentication #######################
  tenant <- "your-tenant-here"
  app <- "your-app-id-here"
  resource <- "your-app-id-here"
  
  token <- get_azure_token(resource, tenant, app, auth_type="authorization_code",
                           authorize_args=list(redirect_uri=redirect), version=2,
                           use_cache=FALSE)
  
  
  ###############Importing the app R files#########
  # load ui elements
  source("ui.R")
  # load server function
  source("server.R")
  
  ui_func <- function(req)
  {
    opts <- parseQueryString(req$QUERY_STRING)
    if(is.null(opts$code))
    {
      auth_uri <- build_authorization_uri(resource, tenant, app, redirect_uri=redirect, version=2)
      redir_js <- sprintf("location.replace(\"%s\");", auth_uri)
      tags$script(HTML(redir_js))
    }
    else ui
  }
  
  # Run the application
  shinyApp(ui = ui_func, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [get an id token using AzureAuth](https://github.com/Azure/AzureAuth#openid-connect). [Azure AD ID tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) can be enriched with [optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) and [claims mapping policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-claims-mapping-policy-type).

Optionally you can use [AzureGraph](https://github.com/Azure/AzureGraph)
`get_user(id)` function to get the user model using the object id which is contained in the id or access token `oid` claim.